# BIG-IP Edge Client fails to update - any way of knowing the reason?

Tags: networking, windows-10, vpn

So I get this update when I start BIG-IP and a bunch of files are downloaded and installed.

[image]

But after a while, the update fails with the following dialog box:

[image]

Any way to know why the update is failing? Perhaps the logs (but where will it be)? I'm launching the application as an Administrator.

Few more details:

**OS:** Windows 10

**BIG-IP Edge Client:** v7171,2018,808,2011

Comment: Sounds like the upgrade installation is failing.  What do the logs indicate the reason is for the failure?

Comment: Here is the log table, search your drive for the appropriate log name>>>>>>https://support.f5.com/csp/article/K32311645#link_05

Comment: Or> On Windows, you can generate a diagnostics report using BIG-IP Edge Client by following these steps:

1.Open BIG-IP Edge Client.
2.Select View Details > Diagnostics Report.